# RAD 7.5, struts 1.1, JDK 1.6 deployment on WAS 7 deployment issues

Tags: rad, java-6

We are trying to migrate WAS 5 to WAS 7. Below is our versions details we are trying to m,igrate:

WSAD 5.1  to      RAD 7.5,  Struts 1.1 to Struts 1.1, JDK 1.4 to  JDK 1.6 and WAS 5     to                    WAS 7

When we deploy JDK 1.6 & Struts 1.1 on WAS 7 using RAD 7.5, we are getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. We tried every possible way of checking the classpath, and looks it's correct.

Comment: Not trying to be picky here, but WAS7 already has JDK 1.6. So why need to deploy it separately?http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=211604